# Fast Fourier Transforms for non-trigonometric bases

Tags: algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, fourier-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

The fast Fourier transform allows decomposition into a sin/cos basis in $N \log(N)$ complexity. Can one generalize the algorithm (or the ideas used) to other bases, e.g. orthogonal polynomial bases such as Hermite, Legendre, Chebyshev,...? I have a special interest in Zernike polynomials as well.
If so, how?
If not, what is special about the sin/cos that separates it from the other cases?

Also asked previously on: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647613/fast-fourier-transform-for-non-trigoniometric-bases/1730645#1730645
not having quite a satisfying answer yet.

Also, in a related question here on MO ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76013/why-is-the-fast-fourier-transform-efficient)), I see pointing to [this document](http://www.mceliece.caltech.edu/publications/GDL.ps) on why the FFT would be fast. How could I use this principle on general orthogonal bases?

Comment: Did you have a look at stuff like: https://www.brown.edu/research/projects/scientific-computing/sites/brown.edu.research.projects.scientific-computing/files/uploads/The%20application%20of%20the%20Fast%20Fourier%20Transform%20to%20Jacobi%20polynomial%20expansions.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Related questions have been considered in some depth by Dan Rockmore and collaborators. For more, check out [Rockmore's web page.](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~rockmore/fft.html)